# I use a webBrowser on C# winform to run a tutorial html+js page, the slide page is ok but can not click skip page to call with js function

Tags: javascript, c#, html, winforms

I tried to develop a login page with a tutorial page on C# winforms using webBrowser component, but it is not simple to develop a very smart for slide page.
I use https://www.jssor.com/download.html , its html+js page for my webBrowser, the slide page is ok.
But when I use a onclick to call my js function to tell webBrowser to enter login page, the onclick is not work.
Have any ideal to solve it ?
Or how can it modify for let webBrowser can know that it is time to skip tutorial page and enter login page?

Can download my C# and html+js source code in below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tJnDPF2YJowG_dAVyI9nygVoE4JAQStr/view?usp=sharing

i am tried to modify html page , but still can not click the button.
This page work fine in IE or Chrome but can not be click on C# webbroswer component.
How can I solve it ?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tJnDPF2YJowG_dAVyI9nygVoE4JAQStr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It works without problems, even targeting `.Net 3.5`. But, since you need IE11 to run that script, you should probably target a more recent framework. What's left is to set the WebBrowser Control's `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` to `11001` in the Registry (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER` branch) and re-target your HTML components, moving all the parts inside your project, selecting all files in the 2 folders and set `Copy to Output Directory -> Copy if newer`. Change the URI to `webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"demos/full-window-for-pc.html")));`. Rebuild the Solution.

Comment: Thank Jimi, but I am not very clear to know how to modify my project as above description.

Comment: I had upgrade framework from 3.5 to 4.7.2, but the result still can slide normal but can not onclick  skip page using webbrowser.

Comment: Or it is any others way that can call js from html , the js code as below  function callNative2(){
    count2++;
    if (!external)
        alert("No external");
    //if (!external.sendMyService)
    //    alert("No external.sendMyService");
    var ret = external.sendMyService(count2);
    document.getElementById("head2").innerHTML = ret;
}

Comment: If you mean the Button that activates `callNative2()`, you can click it. It doesn't do anything here, except opening some `alert` messages, but it works. If you want, I can post a modified version of your Form that performs all the Registry operations (sets the compatibility mode to IE11/Edge on startup and removes it on close).